# How to prevent duplicate elements in ASP.NET on postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have

```
<div ID="mydiv" runat="server"></div>
```

I transport mydiv to Container with jQuery

```
$("#mydiv").appendTo('#Container');
```

On PostBack my div is duplicated and I have two same div on my page.

I need in advice how to prevent duplication with help of JS/jQuery.

Comment: Is it possible that the contents of `#Container` is not reset after each postback, so that a new `#mydiv` is added everytime a postback occurs?

Comment: on postback ....shouldnt the div be reset to its initial state.Doesn't seem like it will duplicate...

Comment: Alex Barac, Yes, I think. How I can reset Container with every postback?

Comment: The problem is solved with check out on Postback and set invisibility for my element on postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using following script:

```
 if($("#mydiv").length == 0) {
      //it doesn't exist
      $("#mydiv").appendTo('#Container'); 
    }
```